# method to read resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, resx

what i'm trying to do is to write a method in c# codebehind to read text based on key.
For now i whant to do this for only one language that's why i don't need to use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

```
private ResourceManager rm;
private ResourceReader rr;
public string GetCurrentLanguage(string key)
{ 
    rm = new ResourceManager("~/App_GlobalResources/textFile", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    string result = rm.GetString(key).ToString();
    return result;
}
```

but it doesn't work :(
when i write something like `litWelcome.Text = GetCurrentLanguage("Welcome");` it's returns error.

anyone have idea what's i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for advance:)

**Edited**

ok i get it on my own this is a solution for my problem:

```
public string GetCurrentLanguage(string key)
{

    string result = Resources.textFile.ResourceManager.GetString(key).ToString();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks all for help:)

Comment: "It doesn't work correctly" isn't a good description of the problem. What's happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this file used to store some sort of settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you be looking for [Using Resources for Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but maybe it is the solution you are looking for. This link will give you information on how to use built-in support for localization of your web site in ASP.NET.

Comment: i saw that before i write here. i want to do this but in code behind with my method which will return string with text wich will get from .resx file

Answer (score 0):

Is this line correct?

```
 rm = new ResourceManager("~/App_GlobalResources\textFile"
```

Your edited comment shows:

file is in ~\App_GlobalResources\textFile.resx

Your slashes aren't consistent. Is this a typo in your post, or your code?

Comment: i got this error: 

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "~/App_GlobalResources/textFile.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_Code.f05e1x5g" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Answer (score 0):

try :

**GetGlobalResourceObject** for global resources.

**GetLocalResourceObject** for local resources.

EX:

```
Button1.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Button1.Text").ToString();
Image1.ImageUrl = CType(GetGlobalResourceObject("WebResourcesGlobal","LogoUrl"), String)
```

for more info check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx